# free variable referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, function, variables, error-handling

Hey im having some trouble understanding what I did wrong/finding a way to fix it, can you guys help me?

```
def main():
    Keys = 0
    def Function1():
        global all
        def Function2():
            global all
            print(str(Keys))
        Function2()
        Keys = Keys + 1
    Function1()
main()
```

every time i try to run this i get this error "free variable 'Keys' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think `global all` is doing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `global Keys` for every function. A function thinks that `Keys` is a local variable.

```
def main():
    global Keys
    Keys = 0
    def Function1():
        global Keys
        global all
        def Function2():
            global Keys
            global all
            print(str(Keys))
        Function2()
        Keys = Keys + 1
    Function1()
main()
```

**However**, using `global` is bad. [Here are a list of reasons why using `global` is bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

So, instead of using `global`, you can pass it as an parametre.

```
def main():
    Keys = 0
    def Function1(Keys):
        def Function2(Keys):
            print(str(Keys))
        Function2(Keys)
        Keys = Keys + 1
    Function1(Keys)
main()
```

Also, `all` is a function in python. There is absolutely no need to make it `global`